# Why can't I return same objects from two different functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm not familiar with javascript programming. But I understand most of it concepts.

I have two functions.

```
function func1(){
    return {
        test1: "success"
    };

}
function func2(){
    return
    {
        test2: "success"
    };
}
```

Both functions supposed to return a same object. But when I run it, the first function was successfully return the object, but the second wasn't.

What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Mind the line return after `return`. Due to "ASI" (automatic semi-colon insertion) this will become `return;`

Comment: @evolutionxbox ah I see, thanks